# `TypeError: k.fadeIn(...).children(...).andBack` is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just update my jquery from 1.10.3 to 3.1.1.
Then I keep getting this error on every page. After looking around, it seems like jquery is getting execute multiple time.

So, this is where it happens.

```
$overlay.
hide().
    fadeIn( configs.fadeIn, function(){
        $content.fadeIn( 'fast' ).children().andSelf().bind( 'click', function( e ){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

On line `$content.fadeIn( 'fast' ).children().andSelf()` it has warning - 
jQuery.Deferred exception: `$content.fadeIn( 'fast' ).children().andSelf()` is not a function.

So I updated `andSelf()` to `addBack()` because jquery 3.1.1 not support to `andSelf()`.But still I get error `$content.fadeIn( 'fast' ).children().addBack()` is not a function.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I don't think there is a `andBack()` function, May be you nee http://api.jquery.com/addback/

Comment: yup i update to addBack() but still getting error